# SeekBar's thumb color is quite blurry

Tags: java, android

I have a seekbar whichs thumb's color is changed dinamically via

> seek.setThumbTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(swatch.getRGB()));

But instead of a solid color for the thumb like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYfsJ.jpg

I get a thumb with a sort of blurry (or non solid) color as this:
https://imgur.com/a/7IYK6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add **alpha value** in your color .Like `#33FF0000` .Remove `33` in color .

Sample

```
mSeekBar.setThumbTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));
mSeekBar.setThumbTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED);
```

Comment: I can't get the Hex of the color, instead, the getRGB() funcion returns an int like this "1879048192" and I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: You can change to this .

Comment: You can use grey color .